# Batch Script is not executing for a string like "Security Operations Group"

Tags: batch-file

Below is my sample code

```
Set Group=Security Operations Group
Set /P Priority=Priority:
if %Group%=="Security Operations Group" if %Priority%=="Low" goto X
```

This is a sample script. Im actually passing the group variable from another application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double quotes are included in the comparison therefore:

```bat
If /I "%Group%"=="Security Operations Group" If /I "%Priority%"=="Low" GoTo X
```

I added the `/I` option to `If` for case insensitivity too.

**[Edit /]** - update based upon new information in comment below

```bat
If /I "%Group%"=="Security Operations Group" (
    If /I "%Priority%"=="Low" GoTo X
    If /I "%Priority%"=="Medium" GoTo Y
)
```

Comment: Hi Compo, Thank You. If priority is Low, then it is going to X. But, if priority is medium it is not going to y. My code is If /I "%Group%"=="Security Operations Group" If /I "%Priority%"=="Medium" GoTo Y just below the goto x

Comment: I have updated my answer based upon your last comment. If you have further issues it would probably be better if you added the rest of your code to your original question as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46372817/edit). If those issues take the question too far from its original remit then consider posting a new question instead.

Comment: Ty Compo, My questions limit is reached.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are included in your comparison.

Because `Group` does not have quotes, but `"Security Operations Group"` does, they do not match.

Change to:

```
if "%Group%"=="Security Operations Group" if "%Priority%"=="Low" goto X
```